# UISplitViewController detail replace segue opens as modal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a `UISplitViewController` in my app with a master and a detailview. The detailview is just an empty `UIViewController` on launch. Once a user selects a `UITableViewCell` in the masterview I'd like to change the detailview to the chosen view. I wrote this function for that:

```
- (void)cellClicked:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == (self.resultArray.count)) {
        [self addCategory:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Also this `prepareForSegue` function:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        NSString *categoryId = [[self.resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"COL2"];

        CategoriesViewController *controller = (CategoriesViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [controller setFeedId:categoryId];
    }
}
```

However, when this is executed it opens the new view as a modal. Which is *not* what I wanted. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your storyboard segue type definition.[image]

I believe you have modally because assume you must use storyboard.